# Can I use a django template to render django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to generate a website's homepage that contains various sections of different types. There's an 'about us' section, a 'recent projects' section etc. My goal is to leave the view logic and template rendering to the individual apps that make up this project (about, portfolio, etc.). My current solution involves constructing a django template dynamically and then rendering it, like so:

---

*in myapp/templatetags/myapp_tags.py:*

```py
@register.simple_tag
def render_sections(sections):
    template = ""
    for section in sections:
        if section.type == "about":
            template += "{% load about %}"
            template += "{% render_about_section %}"
        elif section.type == "portfolio":
            template += "{% load portfolio %}"
            template += "{% render_portfolio_section %}"
    return render_to_string(template)
```

*in templates/index.html:*

```html
{% load myapp_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% render_sections %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Since I'm already constructing a template on the fly, I was wondering: Why couldn't I use django's template system to render django templates? An example template that could replace the above code would be:

```html
{% for s in sections %}
{% load {{s.type}} %}
{% render_{{s.type}}_section %}}
{% endfor %}
```

What could I do to make this work? And are there any better ways to render a list of heterogeneous items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question in the Django documentation:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#limitations-with-string-literals
>
> “Django’s template language has no way to escape the characters used for its own syntax.”

I have solved the problem by replacing the custom `render_[app]_section` templatetags with view functions that take a request object and return a string. For instance, here's the `render_section` function of the portfolio app:

```
def render_section(request)
    projects = Project.objects.filter(featured=True)
    return render_to_string("portfolio/section.html", {
        'projects': projects,
    })
```

I have created one custom templatetag (`render`) that knows how to call an individual app's `render_section` view. Here's the template I use to render the homepage:

```
{% for section in sections %}
{% render section %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = '{{ %s }}'` to your settings. This will replace every invalid variable with `{{ variable_name }}`, as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables).

But this has some major drawbacks:

- it is a setting, so you can't change it for only some templates (and switching it dynamically is just evil)
- it only works for simple variables tags, not more complex stuff (like `{% for x in y %}`)

Not really a full answer, but it might help someone.